# Como omitir determinados argumentos para as quais foram dados valores padrão nos parâmetros do protótipo da função?

Tags: c++, parâmetros

Como omitir específicos argumentos da função em C++ para as quais foram dados valores padrão nos parâmetros do protótipo da função?

Por ex. como omitir o segundo argumento (b = 4 por padrão), passando o primeiro e ultimo?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int SOMA(int a=2, int b=4, int c=5)
{
  int s;
  s=a+b+c;
  return (s);
}

int main ()
{
    //b e c omissos
  cout << SOMA(1) << '\n'; //10
    //b omisso
  cout << SOMA(1,,2) << '\n'; //erro

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Acredito que isto é uma funcionalidade que apenas linguagens que permitem a chamada da função com parâmetros nomeados possuem, como o [Python](https://ideone.com/1RnP6m).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até existem algumas técnicas para permitir isto mas tudo tão complicado, precisa tanto trabalho e em geral tem custo de processamento que não vale o esforço, é muito mais simples usar o valor.

C++ não permite que se omita um argumento no meio, depois de omitir um argumento, todos os seguintes precisam ser omitidos também. E obviamente que depois de ter um parâmetro com valor *default* não pode ter um sem um valor *default*.

Answer (score 0):

***Argumentos Padrões para Funções***

O C++ permite a uma função associar uma valor padrão para um parâmetro quando nenhum argumento correspondente for usado na chamada
   da função.

```
void f (int i = 1)
{
.
.
}
```

Na chamada se usar

```
f(10) // recebe 10 como parâmetro
f() // recebe 1 que é o valor default.
```

Outro exemplo:

```
void myfunc (int i=5, double d=1.23);
myfunc (12, 3.45) // usara os valores 12 e 3.45
myfunc (3) // usara como myfunc( 3, 1.23)
myfunc () // usara como myfunc(5, 1.23)
```

> Não é permitido omitir o primeiro parâmetro e passar só o segundo. Só
>   se pode omitir da direita para a esquerda. Se tem 5 parâmetros para se
>   omitir o terceiro, também deve se omitir o quarto e o quinto.